# Which connector is this on my camera?

Tags: identification, connector, camera

I'm currently investigating an Azure Percept vision device which apparently has 2x MIPI ports as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-percept/azure-percept-vision-datasheet). The back of the module looks like this. One of the connectors to which a camera is attached is marked with an arrow:

[image]

These don't look like the MIPI connectors I know. Does someone know which connector is shown here?

Comment: *These don't look like the MIPI I know* What should a MIPI connector look like? I'm going to say that there are no rules for that, the MIPI specification doesn't tell you what connectors you should use. Also consider that these are proprietary connectors and that the interface could also be proprietary meaning that how they work might only be known to the designers of this product.

Comment: Thanks @Bimpelrekkie that explains it. I was under the impression that the connector is standardized. If you create an answer, I'll accept it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector is MIPI, specific to this board.

MIPI CSI-2 doesn’t define a connector, only the signal set and protocol. There are a multiplicity of connectors in use, each specific to the platform.

There are a few de-facto CSI-2  connector standards that are popular, such as those used for Raspberry Pi (and I suppose, through the dint of Microsoft, the one shown, mated to a specific Sony camera module.) But it’s a mess otherwise.

To add to the confusion, CSI-2 supports:

- different number of lanes
- different lane speeds
- different bit-depths and encodings
- different PHYs (D-PHY vs. C-PHY)

And… the cameras don’t have common APIs, while the manufacturers are very stingy with docs and support (looking at you, Sony.)

Big picture: any platform you buy, make sure it supports the cameras you need.